# Why did Obi-Wan disappear instead of being cut in two pieces?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, obi-wan-kenobi

In *A New Hope*, at the climax of the duel, we are led to believe Obi-Wan turns instantly into a force ghost. Why did he not get cut in two, similar to how Anakin was diced in episode 3, taking away Vader's long-awaited retribution?

Comment: also related: [What happened to Obi-Wan Kenobi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12205/what-happened-to-obi-wan-kenobi/12213#12213)

Answer (score 4):

The quote below is taken from the [Star Wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_ghost), apparently Qui Gon Gin rediscovered the force ghost ability and Obi Wan developed the technique of one's body disappearing. He even taught Yoda how to do it. Unfortunately the wiki does not cite where those paragraphs come from.

> Death for those Jedi were different: their spirits could retain their
>   individuality and could return as voices, dreams, or apparitions at
>   will, so that they could help those in need of their guidance. On
>   death, their bodies vanished; this was not the case with Qui-Gon,
>   however, probably being a technique evolved by Obi-Wan and Yoda, under
>   Qui-Gon's guidance.
>
> Darth Vader learned of this ability through Darth Sidious, and upon
>   his death, the spirits of Kenobi and Yoda completed his training by
>   granting him the last step in becoming a spirit. Anakin's spirit
>   appeared as that of his younger self, prior to his fall to the dark
>   side.

It is also likely that the age of the film impacts this. Perhaps Lucas had some scrapped idea for Obi Wan. Not knowing just how big Star Wars was going to get.

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

1. Obi-Wan knew the secret to becoming a force ghost.
2. Anakin (Vader) didn't actually die.

   2.5. If they *had* made it so Anakin (Vader) used the force to recreate his missing appendages, they could have been liable for lawsuit from the creators of [The Venture Bros](http://venturebrothers.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Limb).

Comment: `2.5. If they had made it so Anakin (Vader) used the force to recreate his missing appendages, they could have been liable for lawsuit from the creators of The Venture Bros.`  WAT???